# Versions of play

Tags: playframework

What version of play was used in 2009? 
Can you tell me in which year, which series came out?

Comment: I hate to be that "references Wikipedia" guy, but [if you look on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Framework#History) the only version available in 2009 was version 1.0. Version 1.1 was released towards the end of 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeline for Play framework releases is provided here [link](https://www.playframework.com/releases).

> For any technology or framework, information regarding Releases or Migrations is usually provided in their documentation. Kindly do check the documentation.